# Optimize bulk insert speed for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, seed

I have a PostgreSQL database on an Amazon EC2 instance, and I am trying to seed the database with 100M lines of data (I have 10 files of 10M lines each). I used the secure copy (scp) command to move the csv files into the EC2 instance. When I try to copy the csv files into the database, it is taking way too much time. Is there a way to fasten the procedure?

Here is my schema.sql file:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS reviews_db;

CREATE DATABASE reviews_db; 

\c reviews_db;

CREATE TABLE reviews (
id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
houseId INT NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
picture VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
reviewText TEXT NOT NULL,
reviewDate VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
accuracyRating INT NOT NULL,
locationRating INT NOT NULL,
communicationRating INT NOT NULL,
checkinRating INT NOT NULL,
cleanlinessRating INT NOT NULL,
valueRating INT NOT NULL,
overallRating DECIMAL NOT NULL

);

CREATE INDEX ON reviews (houseId);
```

Then, on my EC2 instance, I run this command to seed the database :

```
pv ./reviews1.csv | psql -U postgres -d reviews_db -c "COPY reviews FROM STDIN with (FORMAT csv);"
```

Note: my reviews1.csv file is 3.1GB, and it is uploading at a speed of 200kb/s

Comment: Try dropping the index before importing, and re-creating it afterwards. With the index there, PostgreSQL must add index entries one at a time as the rows are inserted; it's much quicker to create an index across the whole dataset once it's all in place.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion from @Timshel, also remove the `primary key` from your create table statement. You can add this constraint right after the import is done, together with the index. Of course, it will only work in case you have a certain control of your csv file ;-) good luck!